# Show/hide listview item onclick

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I've `ListView` which shows rows "headers" and I want to make possibly to open "bodies" on tap and close it on tap again. Everybody can imagine it (it's like an `Expandable ListView`). So I don't want to use `Expandable ListView` but can't make to disappear "body" of my rows. Here is the code :

```
feedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View view, int position, long arg) {             
            LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lInfo);
            ImageView div = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.divider);

           switch(body.getVisibility()){
                case (View.GONE): {                       
                    body.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    div.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.w("body vis",""+body.getVisibility());
                    Log.w("set visible","VISIBLE!");
                }
                break;
               case (View.VISIBLE):{                       
                   body.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   div.setVisibility(View.GONE);
               }
               break;

              }

        }
    });
}
```

My activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">




<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/fon1">

<com.susudashonline.ParallaxListView

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lvContacts"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:divider="#00ffffff"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:clickable="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>



<ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="#002d1816"
android:dividerHeight="2dp"
android:background="#D92d1816"/>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And my **list_item** layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:background="#2d1816"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/divider"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imgDesc"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"

  />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lInfo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#CC2d1816"

    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="address"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDekanat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmailTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSiteTwo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvShedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvWorkTime"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:text="@string/workTime"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llShedule"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShedule1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShedule2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShedule3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvShedule4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTime4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it's my adapter **getView** :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.body = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lInfo);
        holder.facultyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fName);
        holder.mAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAddress);
        holder.mDekanat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDekanat);
        holder.mPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhone);
        holder.mEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
        holder.mSite = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSite);
        holder.mSiteTwo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSiteTwo);
        holder.mEmailTwo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailTwo);
        holder.mShedule = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShedule);
        holder.mTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        holder.mTime1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime1);
        holder.mTime2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime2);
        holder.mTime3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime3);
        holder.mTime4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime4);
        holder.llShedule = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.llShedule);
        holder.mShedule1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShedule1);
        holder.mShedule2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShedule2);
        holder.mShedule3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShedule3);
        holder.mShedule4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvShedule4);
        holder.mWorkTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvWorkTime);
        holder.mDivider = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.divider);
```

//            holder.mImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgContact);

```
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }
    ContactItem contactItem = (ContactItem) listData.get(position);
    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    holder.facultyName.setTypeface(font);
    holder.facultyName.setText(contactItem.getName());
    holder.mEmail.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mDekanat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mPhone.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mSite.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mSiteTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mShedule.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mEmailTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.llShedule.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.mWorkTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.body.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return convertView;
}
```

As you can see I set VISIBILITY to GONE in my adapter and then in OnClick method make VISIBLE and it works! But when I tap on "header" again nothing happens! What should I do to hide body after I already show it?

Comment: What's wrong with ExpandableListView?

Comment: @AlexanderZhak no, I just want to do the thing right this way :)

Comment: Post your layout, please.

Comment: Please be more exact. What happens instead? Please post the items layout .xml. If you could post some pictures?

Comment: @greenapps I added layout and a little bit adapter code :)

Comment: I don't know yet what is the cause. But i see that in onClick you tamper with two views. In the adapter with many more. That should be equal and the same i think.

Comment: @greenapps no, I use only `body` (ListView) in my code (in onClick) if `body.getVisibility() == View.GONE` I show `body` and it works pretty good! Then I want tap on row again and make `body` GONE

Comment: I was talking about setting the visibility. So why you do set visibility of div too? That are two.

Comment: @greenapps it's just a divider between header and body.. just colored line. it doesn't really matter

Comment: Ok but you should do the same in the adapter as i said earlier. No pictures?

Comment: Is this for the ListView or the ParallaxListView?

Comment: @greenapps it's for the ParallaxListView. does it really matter?

Comment: Don't know. Can be. I know nothing of that view. I would prefer helping you with a 'normal' ListView.

Comment: @greenapps let's imagine that it's regular `ListView`

Comment: ;-) tomorrow there is another day...

Comment: @greenapps the problem is only in my switch-case construction. when I click frist time it shows the body.. I want to collapse it when I click the second time but nothing happens :(

Comment: That i know from the start! Did you check that the Log.w() prints the right case? Add a log to the other case too. Or use Toast's.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Expandable Library](https://github.com/traex/ExpandableLayout) to achieve this. It's like ExpandableListview but you have to set layout for header and content ;)

Comment: That looks like a good idea. Thanks for the info. Will try it soon.